# Алгоритм преобразования списочных данных

Tags: xml, алгоритм, html, парсер

Подскажите, пожалуйста, может кто встречал код, который строку вида

```
(p "qqqqaaaa" (tr (td "www") (td "eee")))
```

Преобразует в html или xml вида:

```
< p >qqqqaaaa< tr >< td > www < /td > < td> eee< /td> < /tr> < /p>
```

На входе тегов будет немного, т.е. только основные элементы форматирования, без излишеств.
Нужен самый простецкий парсер, на php или javascript, или алгоритм.

Answer (score 1):

Пример такой функции. В данных ( в (td "www") это www ) нельзя использовать _"_.
Замечу, что это не самая быстрая реализация.

```
function parse(str){
  var re1 = /\(([\w]+) \"([^\"]+)\"\)/,
      re1_ = '"<$1>$2</$1>"',
      re2 = /\"[ ]+\"/,
      re2_ = '';

  var tmp;

  while( ( tmp = str.replace( re1, re1_ ) ) != str ){
    str = tmp.replace( re2, re2_ );
  }

  return str;
}

str = '(p "qqqqaaaa" (tr (td "www") (td "eee")))';
parse( str );
```

Comment: спасибо, я уже сам справился

Answer (score 0):

Структура информации -- список в лиспе/scheme. Соответственно такие строки лисповые языки понимают в лоб, а уж вывести их в xml-формате должно быть несложно. Если нужен другой язык, то задача парсинга лисповых списков в этом конкретном языке наверняка решалась неоднократно.

Comment: Действительно, список приходит из лиспа, но парсер нужен javascript или php. Вот ищу конкретику, прошу помощи у сообщества, ибо самостоятельно пока не нашел.